# Movie where man alerts police because wife is missing, but has killed her himself

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'd like to identify a movie (possibly made for TV, but in full movie length) I watched on TV in the late 80s or early 90s.

The action takes place in winter in a small town in northwestern USA or Canada. An man reports his wife missing to the police. (I think they were in town for holiday, or rented a house for the winter).

He suspects a crime, seems very worried, and gets angry at the police as the investigation does not seem to go anywhere, or they do not seem to take the matter seriously. He remains the point-of-view character during the whole movie. At the end the surprise reveal is that he himself killed his wife and hid the body, and the police actually suspected him all along and only played dumb.

I also remember that the movie was based on a theatre play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds something like [Vanishing Act](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092148/) (1986)

> In the Rocky Mountains, Harry Kenyon seeks out his missing wife Chris in the Winter Parade. Harry meets Lieutenant Rudameyer and tells that him he is from San Francisco and has just married Chris, from Philadelphia, in Las Vegas. They traveled to the Rockies on honeymoon and they had an argument the previous day, and Chris left their isolated cabin in her car. Harry also says that he is worried about her disappearance since she is not a good driver. Harry returns to his cabin and receives a phone call from the local priest, Father Macklin, who summons him to go to the church. Father Macklin tells says Chris is in the church waiting for him. When Harry sees Chris, he tells that she is not his wife; but the woman knows details of their lives and Harry is discredited by the evidences. Is a stranger impersonating Chris or is Harry delusional?

Answer (score -1):

I remember seeing this movie on South African TV as a child  - it was translated into Afrikaans and clearly a stage play. Years later, when I was a student, I managed to track down the drama script - it was originally a French play. More than 15 years later, (tonight) I suddenly remember it again but just couldn't for the life of me remember the Afrikaans title, let alone the French one! But thanks to the answer above, I could track it down again. It's Trap for a Lonely Man, (Piège pour un homme seul) by Robert Thomas. The translated title in Afrikaans was Lokval vir ‘n Eensame Man. Vanishing Act is indeed based on the play.